# justify-content: space-between; not changing (layout?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to html, css, js and especially new to stack overflow so hello all. I am currently following a tutorial where I am making a calculator but noticed when they tutorial added space-between did not adjust anything on my live preview like it did in the tutorial. I went back over the tutorial and didn't notice anything that I missed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Calculator | Kjb</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <section class="screen">
            0
        </section>

        <section class="calc-buttons">
            <div class="calc-buttons-row">
                <button class="calc-button double">
                    C
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    &larr;
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    &divide;
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="calc-buttons-row">
                <button class="calc-button">
                    7
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    8
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    9
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    &times;
                </button>    
            </div>

            <div class="calc-buttons-row">
                <button class="calc-button">
                    4
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    5
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    6
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    &minus;
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="calc-buttons-row">
                <button class="calc-button">
                    1
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    2
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    3
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    &plus;
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="calc-buttons-row">
                <button class="calc-button triple">
                    0
                </button>
                <button class="calc-button">
                    &equals;
                </button>
            </div>

        </section>

    </div>


  <script src="script.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

```
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(320deg, #eb92be, #ffef78, #63c9b4);
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-display: swap;
    height: inherit;
    justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper{
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
    color: #232323;
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.30);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.34);
    flex-basis: 400px;
    height: 540px;
    padding: 20px 25px;
}

.screen{
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
    color: #232323;
    font-size: 35px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 326px;
}

.calc-button-row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 5% 0;
}

.calc-button{
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1)
}
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Comment: apologize if the formatting is off I think I added the html to the main post?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your spellings are wrong. In css, instead of `.calc-buttons-row` you have used `.calc-button-row` please check all the class names properly.

Comment: Thank you I looked straight over it. I will be sure to check spelling and class names from now on.